# MPI struct error

Tags: c, struct, char, mpi

I am trying to send a struct using MPI_Bcast function but i am getting an error.
**Structure definition ::**

```
typedef struct _data{
      char table[5][20];
}data;
```

**Data Type Creation ::**

```
data t[100];
const int nitems=1;
int blocklengths[1] = {200};
MPI_Datatype types[1] = {MPI_CHAR};
MPI_Datatype mpi_d_type;
MPI_Aint     offsets[1];
offsets[0] = offsetof(data, table);
MPI_Type_create_struct(nitems, blocklengths, offsets, types, &mpi_d_type);
MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_d_type);
if (myid == ROOT) {
//reading values from stdin and storing into 't'
}
MPI_Bcast( t, 100, mpi_d_type, ROOT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

**Following is the error,which i am getting..**

```
[surya:00652] [ 0] 0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8c65892a _sigtramp + 26
[surya:00652] [ 1] 0   ???                                 0x0000000000000000 0x0 + 0
[surya:00652] [ 2] 0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8c6b304c getenv + 29
[surya:00652] [ 3] 0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8c674b35 _simple_asl_init + 25
[surya:00652] [ 4] 0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8c66bfd0 pthread_once + 87
[surya:00652] [ 5] 0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8c6748f8 _simple_asl_log_prog +    48
[surya:00652] [ 6] 0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8c6b0d37 __stack_chk_fail + 183
[surya:00652] [ 7] 0   a.out                               0x0000000109a14e3a main + 810
[surya:00652] [ 8] 0   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff86b0c7e1 start + 0
[surya:00652] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 1 with PID 652 on node surya exited on signal 11 (Segmentation      fault: 11).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `blocklengths` has a value that's double the number of characters in the struct declaration. An array of `5*20` only has 100 `char` elements, but you tell MPI each one has 200.